# Can't seem to get the JOptionPane drop-down to work properly

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm pretty sure that it should be fine but I keep getting this warning!

```
String[] trollDo= {"Try and sneak the horses away.",
                   "Go back and tell the others.", 
                   "Kill the trolls."};
String trollChoice =(String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
           "What will "+playerName+" do?",null,JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
           trollDo,trollDo[0]);
```

Comment: are you getting a warning or any error? if it is error then what is it?

Comment: @10sw33 comment flagged

Comment: @10sw33 Everybody.  Warnings are good indicator that your expectations and the compilers conflict and could indicate a change to the API and it's working

Answer (score 3):

You should be getting a compile error, something like...

```
error: no suitable method found for showInputDialog(<null>,String,<null>,int,String[],String)
    String trollChoice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                                             ^
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Object,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object,Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object,String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method JOptionPane.showInputDialog(Component,Object,String,int,Icon,Object[],Object) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error
```

Which means you are missing the `icon` parameter...

```
String trollChoice = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null,
                "What will " + playerName + " do?", 
                null,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null, // This one here
                trollDo, 
                trollDo[0]);
```

Make sure you're consulting the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)) and making use of your IDE to select and fill method parameters

Answer (score 0):

You have to give proper parameters.

public static Object showInputDialog(**Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int messageType, Icon icon, Object[] selectionValues, Object initialSelectionValue**) throws HeadlessException

```
 JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, e, playerName, messageType, null, trollDo, playerName);
```

Prompts the user for input in a blocking dialog where the initial selection, possible selections, and all other options can be specified. The user will able to choose from selectionValues, where null implies the user can input whatever they wish, usually by means of a JTextField. initialSelectionValue is the initial value to prompt the user with. It is up to the UI to decide how best to represent the selectionValues, but usually a JComboBox, JList, or JTextField will be used.

Parameters:

***parentComponent -*** the parent Component for the dialog

***message -*** the Object to display

***title -*** the String to display in the dialog title bar

***messageType -*** the type of message to be displayed: ERROR_MESSAGE, INFORMATION_MESSAGE, WARNING_MESSAGE, QUESTION_MESSAGE, or PLAIN_MESSAGE

***icon -*** the Icon image to display

***selectionValues -*** an array of Objects that gives the possible selections

***initialSelectionValue -*** the value used to initialize the input field

Returns:

user's input, or null meaning the user canceled the input

Throws:

HeadlessException - if GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless returns true